# How can I remove duplicates with constraints in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm completely new to Pig and I'm having some trouble.

I have a list of data and I want to remove duplicates. However, the catch is that duplicates are defined by having the same username and having the access time within the same threshold. For example:

A: [User1, 10]

B: [User1, 20]

C: [User1, 11]

D: [User2, 10]

If the threshold is 2, A and C should be identified as duplicates. How do I do this in Pig? It currently looks like I should use some combination of a UDF and DISTINCT, but I'm not sure how to tell DISTINCT what I want to define "duplicate" as.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "threshold"? did you actually mean "distance"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=load 'data' as (user, access_time:int) using ...;
b=foreach a generate user as user, (access_time > $threshold ? $threshold : access_time) as access_time;
c=group b by user;
d=foreach c generate group as user, FLATTEN(DISTINCT(b.access_time)) as access_time;
store d;
```

i didn't test the script, but the idea is to group by user, replace everything that is above threshold to threshold and then use the builtin distinct UDF.